# Conjugating pairs of Paulis to each other with a non-entangling Clifford

Tags: pauli-gates, clifford-group

This a follow-up question to [Conjugating pairs of Paulis to each other with a Clifford](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/31809/conjugating-pairs-of-paulis-to-each-other-with-a-clifford)

We call a Clifford gate local if it is a tensor product of single qubit Clifford gates.

We call a Clifford gate non entangling if it is generated by single qubit Clifford gates and permutations.

Let $ A,B $ be two Paulis with the same weight $ wt(A)=wt(B) $. Then there always exists some non-entangling Clifford $ C $ such that
$$
CAC^\dagger=B
$$

Let $ A_1,A_2 $ be two Paulis which anticommute. Let $ B_1,B_2 $ be another pair of Paulis that anticommute. (Or you can assume that both pairs commute the answer shouldn't change.) Moreover suppose that $ wt(A_1)=wt(B_1) $ and $ wt(A_2)=wt(B_2) $.

Does there always exist some non-entangling Clifford $ C $ such that simultaneously
$$
CA_1C^\dagger=B_1 
$$
$$
CA_2C^\dagger=B_2
$$

Comment: Are you allowing permutations as well? $ZI$ and $IZ$ aren’t locally Clifford equivalent.

Comment: @squiggles great point! I should have said equivalent by local Cliffords + permutations (in other words equivalent by non-entangling Cliffords)